Implementing Safe Tx Builder in Custom network safe-infrastructure
I don't see the transaction builder in our Safe Wallet Web UI (after clicking new transaction menu).
I tried running https://github.com/safe-global/safe-react-apps/tree/development/apps/tx-builder locally and added it with Add custom safe apps but it says the contents of the app are blocked, like here

Is there some configuration on CFG or CGW that I have to do to enable them?

Thanks for your question.
It is hard to debug without much information.

Did you make sure to enable the safe-apps in the config-service for your chain?
We had a bug that blocked localhost from the web app which we fixed just now. Is your issue resolved?

Otherwise, could you copy the browser console logs, please?

Yes, it worked. I only added the Safe app from the UI and not directly to the config service so that might be the case. But I rebuilt the containers and it works, thanks
